# stm32: After 20 time add new node to linked list, then the system has crashed

Tags: stm32, allocation

Edit: 2019/1/22
(I'v solve this problem by increase heapsize from 512 byte to 2048 byte)

[sory for my bad english first !]

I have a linked list, and sometime i add some new node to this, it work fine on visual studio (visual c++ compiler) but there is problem when using ARM Compiler V5.

My code run on stm32f103vet6, affter 20 time add new node to link list then system has crashed, the pc jump to HardFault_Handler. I don't know why ? My code work fine on window (visual studio).

i've google for a few day, but have no ideal

// This is my code

```
typedef struct OutputLineStructure   
{

    int16_t OP_Name;
    uint16_t Time1;
    uint16_t Value;
    uint16_t Time2;
    struct  OutputLineStructure *pNext;
    struct  OutputLineStructure *pPrev;

} OutputLine;
//

typedef struct StoryboardStruct   
{
    OutputLine *Line;
    uint16_t Lenght;
    uint16_t ID;
} StoryboardStructure;
//

StoryboardStructure _Storyboard[12]; 

// Set break point inside to view exeption
char SE_File[100] = {[0 ... 99]  = 0};
char SE_Function[100] = {[0 ... 99] = 0};
char SE_Comment[150] = {[0 ... 99] = 0};
void SystemFault_Exception(char* File, char* Function, char* Comment, uint32_t ErrorCode)
{
    sprintf(SE_File, "%s", File);

    sprintf(SE_Function, "%s", Function);

    sprintf(SE_Comment, "%s", Comment); 

    uint32_t Code = ErrorCode;

    delayMs(10); // Set break point here 
}
//

void StoryboardInit(StoryboardStructure *MyStoryboard, uint16_t ID)
{
    MyStoryboard->Lenght = 0;
    MyStoryboard->Line = NULL;
    MyStoryboard->ID = ID;
}
//

void StoryboardAllInit(void)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i< 12; i++)
    {
        StoryboardInit(_Storyboard+i, i+1);
    }
}
//

void StoryboardAddLine(StoryboardStructure *MyStoryboard, int16_t _Name, uint16_t _Time1, uint16_t _Value, uint16_t _Time2)
{
    if (MyStoryboard->Lenght == 0)
    {
        if (MyStoryboard->Line != NULL) 
        {
            SystemFault_Exception("storyboard","StoryboardAddLine","HeadLine is not NULL",0);
            while(1); // the pc never jump to this point
        }
        OutputLine *NewLine = (OutputLine*)malloc(sizeof(OutputLine));

        NewLine->OP_Name = _Name;
        NewLine->pNext = NULL;
        NewLine->pPrev = NULL; 

        NewLine->Time1 = _Time1; //Set break point and error occur here
        NewLine->Time2 = _Time2; //Set break point and error occur here
        NewLine->Value = _Value; //Set break point and error occur here

        MyStoryboard->Line = NewLine;
        MyStoryboard->Lenght ++;
    }
    else
    {
        OutputLine *NewNode = (OutputLine*)malloc(sizeof(OutputLine)); 
        NewNode->OP_Name = _Name;
        NewNode->Time1 = _Time1;
        NewNode->Time2 = _Time2;
        NewNode->Value = _Value;


        OutputLine *Scan = MyStoryboard->Line;
        while (Scan->pNext != NULL)
        {
            Scan = Scan->pNext;
        }

        Scan->pNext = NewNode;
        NewNode->pPrev = Scan;
        NewNode->pNext = NULL;
        MyStoryboard->Lenght++;
    }
}
//

int main(void )
{
    StoryboardAllInit();

    for (int id = 1; id< 10; id++)
    {
        for (int line = 0; line < 10; line ++)
        StoryboardAddLine(_Storyboard + id-1,id + line,0,0,0);
          // When ID = 3 and line  = 0. system has crashed
    }

    while(1)
    {

    }
}
//
```

see main function, for loop, when (id == 3 and line == 0) then system has crash. 
See StoryboardAddLine function, block (MyStoryboard->Lenght == 0), error occur when i set properties for MyStoryboard, like:  NewLine->Time1 = _Time1;

Thank for your help  !

Comment: How big is your heap? In the embedded world you should avoid dynamic allocation if possible.

Comment: Pet peeve (aka "I used to do this all the time): `Lenght` should be `Length`.

Comment: thank for your advices  ! I've increase heapsize from 512(byte) to 2048 (byte) and stm32 work fine, thank you very much !